# A question about Template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I know the basics of templates in C++, but I am still learning it.
I have a question regarding to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PNG {
public:
    static void draw() {
        cout<<"PNG drawing"<<endl;
    }
};

template <typename Image>
void draw() {
    Image::draw();
}


int main() {

    draw<PNG>();
}
```

the function `draw()`, I pass the type `Image` to it, and it will use `draw()` method of the `Image`.

```
template <typename Image>
    void draw() {
        Image::draw();
    }
```

Here, I pass `Image` and want to use `draw()` method inside of `Image`, but template function `draw()` has no parameter. So my question is, if I call this template function `draw()` in `main` in this way: `draw<PNG>();` is it allowed?
And how the template function `draw()` knows the `PNG` is a class, and how the class member function `draw()` is called?

Comment: Are you asking if you can call draw without instantiating it with Image as it's template parameter? That is, if you can use `draw();` rather than `draw<PNG>();`? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: The original version of the question was misleading because the template parameter was invisible. Formatting as code revealed that "draw()" was actually "draw<PNG>()".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your first question**

> if I call this template function
>   draw() in main in this way: draw(); is
>   it allowed?

As you have realised, the compiler cannot *deduce* by itself that you mean `draw<PNG>` if there are no function arguments from which to figure it out.

So, you have to write (as you already do):

```
int main() {
   draw<PNG>();
}
```

You cannot omit the template parameter here.

**Your second question**

> and how the template function draw()
>   knows the PNG is a class, and how the
>   class member function draw() is
>   called?

When the function template (A) is instantiated with parameter `PNG`, the resulting function body looks like (B):

```
// A:

template <typename Image>
void draw() {
    Image::draw();
}

// B:

    PNG::draw();
```

The parser knows that, for this to work, `PNG` must be a namespace or a class/struct. If it's not, the function will not compile.

Say you'd called `draw<int>()` instead, for example, your code will try to call `int::draw()`, which is not possible.

Now, due to SFINAE (look it up!) you won't get a compilation error for the broken `int::draw()` call; this particular instantiation will simply be prohibited from existing. You'll probably be told that there is "no match for function `draw()`", as — discounting the prohibited instantiation — there is no possible overload of a function `draw` that it can pick to use.

Answer (score 3):

```
draw<PNG>();
```

`PNG` is passed to the template parameter `Image`. So, a corresponding template is instantiated by the compiler. In other words, a function generated with the template parameter `Image` being replaced by the call parameter `PNG`.

Since `PNG::draw()` is a static member function it doesn't require instance to call it. So,

```
Image::draw(); => PNG::draw() ; // Template parameter substituted and the call 
                                // is made.
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply call `draw()` in your main function like this:

```
draw();
```

You either need to use it as the template function or the member function.

```
PNG dummy;
dummy.draw(); // Okay.
dummy::draw(); // Okay.
draw<PNG>(); // Okay.
draw(); // Not okay.
```

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.  The `typename` keyword, in this case, signifies that the function will accept an object of an unknown type that happens to have a `draw()` member.

Comment: (a) Instantiating "dummy" objects in order to call static member functions is wasteful. (b) `dummy::draw()` is wrong: you mean `PNG::draw()`.

Comment: @Tomalak I did that to reinforce that it was a member of `PNG`, rather than some magical detached function somewhere.  I'll accept that downvote, though, since the other answers explain it far better than mine does.